# Regexp to take all numbers from the string in JavaScript and php

Tags: regex, numbers

Was playing around with regexp to remove all numbers from string

I came up to this:

```
   /([^0-9])$/
```

But it works only if string looks like this, e.g. Name123 but if you enter Name123Name than it doesn't work?

Can't understand why?

Any ideas?

Best regards,
Ilia

Comment: What language is this for? There's almost certainly a better way to do what you want, but it's hard to say what without knowing which language you are using.

Comment: I use javascript and jQuery as user side and same thing I do with PHP. Here is how I apply it for user side: var a = city.val(); var filter = /([^\d])/;if(filter.test(a)){ do something}

Comment: Isn't your logic backwards? You're testing if it contains at least one non-digit. But it could still contain digits. What is "do something"? Is that the code that's supposed to produce an error message, or the code that's supposed to run when there's no error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regular expression finds *one* character not in `[0-9]` at the *end of the string*.

To check if there is a digit anywhere in the string, remove the anchors:

```
/[0-9]/
```

To check that all characters are not digits, add a start of string anchor too:

```
/^[^0-9]+$/
```

This approach is called a blacklist - a list of characters you *don't* want to allow. Note that it's often better to create a whitelist instead - a list characters that you *do* want to allow.

Answer (score 1):

remove the `$` at the end, because that matches the end of the string. Also you can use `\d` to match a digit instead of `[0-9]` depending on the language you're using.

so in your example `/[0-9]$/` matches Name123 because the 123 appears at the end of the string, thus matches the `$` anchor. But in the other example, Name123Name, the `$` anchor doesn't match because the digits are in the middle of the string.

Comment: Funny, but I tried that and it doesn't work. Here is how I apply it: var a = city.val(); var filter = /([^\d])/;if(filter.test(a)){ do something}

Comment: Ahh, javascript... I'm more of a perl person. Not the right person to ask about javascript